# Unknown MySQL server host ''backenddb'' (-3) in Flask app with Docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, docker-compose

I'm trying to learn docker and I found this course on educative.io to do so.

Why I do `docker compose up` in the /Docker directory, everything runs fine but when I try to navigate to "127.0.0.1:5000" in my browser I get that error.

I have the following docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    # Path to dockerfile.
    # '.' represents the current directory in which
    # docker-compose.yml is present.
    build: .

    # Mapping of container port to host
    
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    # Mount volume 
    volumes:
      - "C:/Users/Docker/:/code"

    # Link database container to app container 
    # for rechability.
    links:
      - "database:backenddb"

  database:

    # image to fetch from docker hub
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7

    # Environment variables for startup script
    # container will use these variables
    # to start the container with these define variables. 
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"
      - "MYSQL_USER=testuser"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin123"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=backend"
    # Mount init.sql file to automatically run 
    # and create tables for us.
    # everything in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder
    # is executed as soon as container is up nd running.
    volumes:
      - "C:/Users/Docker/db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql"
```

And the code that contains the flask env and all the requirements can be found in this repo:

https://github.com/venky8283/Docker

You only need to checkout to commit: 4de325cf1da2428e757be4f2bcc53f35c384c598

Answer (score 1):

your database service is named "database"

by default it will create a hostname "database" pointing to your mysql server, which will be reachable by your "web" service.
Then you should use this name and not "db" when configuring your code.

also you specified a "links" property that you can completely delete to make it work.

If you want to keep it, and also keep the "db" hostname to access the database from your web service, then do it like that

```
links:
      - "database:db"
```

Comment: I'm sorry @Raphael.. That was a typo :( 
The error I'm actually getting is this : Unknown MySQL server host ''backenddb'' (-3)